# Remove All RoleAssignemnts Except Current Loggedin User

Tags: item-added, role-assignment

I have written code for removing all `roleassignments` for a `splistitem` using the `itemadded()` and `itemupdated()` `eventhandler` . But my requirement is how can I prevent the removal of `currentloggedin user` instead of removing everyone ?

So, I just **DONT want** to remove the current logged in user from the item's `RoleAssignemnts`. How to achieve this?

```
if (!CurrentListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
            {
                CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments;
                for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignmentSingle = SPRoleAssColn[i];
                    System.Type t = roleAssignmentSingle.Member.GetType();
                    if (t.Name == "SPGroup" || t.Name == "SPUser")
                        SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to add the following before your if (`if (t.Name == "SPGroup" || t.Name == "SPUser")`) statement:

```
if (roleAssignmentSingle.Member.LoginName == properties.UserLoginName)
                    continue;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
if (roleAssignmentSingle.Member.ID != SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID)
{
   SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that SPContext.Current is null in event receivers.

Comment: @DamjanTomic, if i use continue keyword along with your code, will my code OMIT the current user's permissions and remove ALL OTHER ROLE ASSIGNMENTS? this is what i need, i mean, i SHOULD NOT remove the roleassignments of currentlogged in user and SHOULD REMOVE remaining users or spgruops.

Comment: @SaMolPP: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thnx for the reply. Now,if i want to apply a custom permission for the current list item for current logged user "mycustomNoDeletePermission" , how to achieve this ? Currently , the current logged in user has Full Control on his document.Now, i wanna change this "FullControl" to "mycustomNoDeletePermission" , for the  currentlistitem.